# similar and dissimilar elements in a cell in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell of form: A = {[7];[];[7,7];[3,4,5];[6,7];[7,7];[7,8];[]};

And I want to find a number of similar and dissimilar elements separately in Matlab How can I accomplish this?

I mean, that element `[3,4,5]` is `1` and The type of the element to be determined.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through the cell array:

```
A = {7;[];[7,7];[3,4,5];[6,7];[7,7];[7,8];[]};
elem = zeros(numel(A),2);
for k = 1:numel(A)
    elem(k,1) = numel(unique(A{k}));
    elem(k,2) = numel(A{k})-elem(k,1);
end
```

The result here is 2-column vector `elem`, where the first vector is the no. of unique elements and the second is the no. of non-uniqe elements:

```
elem =
     1     0
     0     0
     1     1
     3     0
     2     0
     1     1
     2     0
     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the numbers to strings, then use `unique` with all its properties that fit to your purpose.

If you ask about the number of unique and non-unique cells, then do it like that:

```
B= cellfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false);
number_of_unique_cells=numel(unique(B));
number_of_repeated_cells=numel(A)-numel(unique(B));
```